# SQL multiple insertions, row data based on existing rows

Tags: sql, insert, row

I have recently updated my table schema to include a new column, which has one or several possible values depending on the row (I can pull these possible values from another table). I wish to update my table and replace each current single row with one or several new rows, where the old column values all match the original row, and the new column value covers each possible value once.

As an example, suppose I had a table called `Animal`, with columns `AnimalType`, `Size`, `Habitat`, and `Weight`. I add a new column called `Color` - some animals only have one color, some can have one of several possible colors. Suppose I have a row for `Bird` that looks like this:

```
{ AnimalType = Bird, Size = Small, Habitat = Woods, Weight = under 10 pounds, Color = NULL }
```

Now suppose that, according to my other table (call it `AnimalColors`), `Birds` can come in three colors -- red, blue and brown.

I wish to replace that single row with three new rows that look like the following:

```
{AnimalType = Bird, Size = Small, Habitat = Woods, Weight = under 10 pounds, Color = Red}
{AnimalType = Bird, Size = Small, Habitat = Woods, Weight = under 10 pounds, Color = Blue}
{AnimalType = Bird, Size = Small, Habitat = Woods, Weight = under 10 pounds, Color = Brown}
```

I have multiple rows in my `Animals` table and wish to perform this operation on each of them.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at solving this problem by leaving the existing rows as is.

Create new rows with color populated based on the existing rows

Delete the NULL rows (after verifying it looks as expected)

```
-- Add rows with color populated
WITH AnimalColors (AnimalType, Color) AS
(
    SELECT 'bird', 'red'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'bird', 'blue'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'bird', 'brown'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'lizard', 'green'
)
, ExistingRows(AnimalType, Size, Habitat, Weight, Color) AS
(
    SELECT 'bird', 'small', 'woods', 'under 10 pounds', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 'lizard', 'small', 'rocks', 'under 10 pounds', NULL
)
INSERT INTO
    Animal
(
    AnimalType
,   Size
,   Habitat
,   Weight
,   Color
)
SELECT
    ER.AnimalType
,   ER.Size
,   ER.Habitat
,   ER.Weight
,   AC.Color
FROM
    AnimalColors AC
    INNER JOIN
        ExistingRows ER
        ON ER.AnimalType = AC.AnimalType;

-- Manually review values of Animal table
SELECT A.* FROM Animal A ORDER BY A.AnimalType, A.Color;

-- Remove the uncolored rows
DELETE A FROM Animal A WHERE A.Color IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is how I would prefer to do it - I'm still relatively new to SQL and I want to make sure I don't end up losing any existing data.
Edit: posted this before you added the query to your post. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid manually entering the possible colors for each animal? like "For each animal in the Animals table, select all of its possible colors and then perform these inserts." I have approximately 200 rows on which I need to do this operation.

Comment: The `WITH AnimalColors` section is just a place holder to show the concept. I assume you already have that table created and populated with data. Is this incorrect? If you're looking for minimal changes, just replace the contents of the `SELECT 'bird', 'red'` section with `SELECT AnimalType, Color FROM AnimalColors`

Answer (score 1):

D:

You need to add another table for any of those attributes that could have more than one value, or else you're asking for trouble in the future when it comes to updates and deletions (see Normalization).

For example, add an "AnimalColor" table that links back to the Animal table using an AnimalID. Your database could look like this:

```
Animals
AnimalID  AnimalName

AnimalColors
AnimalID  Color
```

Comment: Hi - I have this second table already, but I need to represent each color of each AnimalID as a separate entity now. Copying all existing columns is the first step, but it's possible that these fields may be individually modified in the future.